# Visual Programing Editor in JavaScript for embedded systems with C runtime library

Tags: web-apps, visual-design, embedded-systems

What Visual Programing Editors are out other for embedded systems with this features:

- The program should run standalone in the embedded system by means of a cross compiled C runtime library.
- The editor should run entirely on the web browser depending only on web technologies (HTML + JavaScript + CSS + JSON).
- Support for reusable macros build from simple nodes.
- Open source with a BDS-style permissive license.

Comment: I'm confused as to which pieces run where (and why you'd want that).  I'm guessing the editor runs in a web browser only; the edited "C"(?) program runs in an embedded system.   Where is the compiler? Debugger?  Why can't you simply use a conventional editor on a workstation?   "Simple node".... where is that term defined in your question?

Comment: @IraBaxter After googling a lot: app.flowhub.io (editor for flow based programming, or FBP), MicroFlo.org (FBP runtime for embedded systems)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand your answer.

Comment: What about a debugger? An IDE isn't much use without one